# iPhone - Problem with Distribution Certificate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store, code-signing

I'm trying to publish my app to the app store.

I followed the Apple instructions to create the Distribution Certificates and Provisioning profiles and added them to my XCode Organizer.

When I select Project > Edit Project Settings and check the 'Code Signing Identity - Any iOS Device, my DistributionCertificate/Profile appears correctly.

HOWEVER when I select Target > Edit Active Target, and check the 'Code Signing Identity - Any iOS Device, my DistributionCertificate/Profile is disabled (the same one mentioned above).

I can see the message: "Profile doesn't match application identifer bundleID

What am I doing wrong? And How can I go about enabling the code signing in my Target Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Did you fill in the Identifier in your Target Info Properties settings to be compatible the app ID in your profile, as configured in Apple's on-line Developer Portal.

Comment: my online portal has appID:YVW2UMA3HV.com.yourcompany.ytj  ...however my app uses 'com.yourcompany.ytj' ..whenever i try to insert the YUW2UMA3HV in front of the bundleID in xCode, I keep getting errors.